# Uniqueness of Wedge Product

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

In Lee's smooth manifolds it is an exercise to show that the wedge product
$\wedge \colon \Lambda^k(V)\times \Lambda^l(V) \to \Lambda^{k+l}(V)$ is the unique associative, bilinear and anticommutative map satisfying
$$\varepsilon^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \varepsilon^{i_k} = \varepsilon^I \;\;\;\;\; (\star)$$
To clarify, given a multi-index $I = (i_1,\dots, i_k)$, $\varepsilon^I$ is the covariant $k$-tensor in $\Lambda^k(V)$ defined by
$$\varepsilon^I(v_1,\dots,v_k) = \det\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon^{i_1}(v_1) & \cdots & \varepsilon^{i_1}(v_k)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\varepsilon^{i_k}(v_1) & \cdots & \varepsilon^{i_k}(v_k)
\end{pmatrix}$$
If we take $\omega \in \Lambda^k(V)$ and $\eta \in \Lambda^l(V)$ then we can expand in the usual basis as $\omega = \sum_{I}'\omega_I \varepsilon^I$, $\eta = \sum_J'\eta_J\varepsilon^J$. Taking $*$ to be a map satisfying these four properties, we can write
\begin{align*}
\omega * \eta &= \left(\sum_{I}'\omega_I \varepsilon^I\right)*\left(\sum_J'\eta_J\varepsilon^J\right)\\
&=\sum_I'\omega_I\left(\varepsilon^I*\left(\sum_J'\eta_J\varepsilon^J\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_I'\omega_I\left(\sum_J'\eta_J\left(\varepsilon^I *\varepsilon^J\right)\right)
\end{align*}
At this point all we've used is bilinearity. So if we can prove $\varepsilon^I *\varepsilon^J = \varepsilon^I \wedge\varepsilon^J$ then we are done. Using associativity and the property $(\star)$ we find
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon^I *\varepsilon^J &= (\varepsilon^{i_1} *\cdots *\varepsilon^{i_k})*(
\varepsilon^{j_1} *\cdots*\varepsilon^{j_l})\\
&= \varepsilon^{i_1} *\cdots *\varepsilon^{i_k}*
\varepsilon^{j_1} *\cdots*\varepsilon^{j_l}\\
&= \varepsilon^{IJ}\\
&= \varepsilon^I \wedge \varepsilon^J
\end{align*}
Here the first equality is $(\star)$, the second equality is associativity, the third is $(\star)$ again, and the fourth is an earlier proposition in Lee about the wedge product. But this argument does not use anticommutativity anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: You have essentially baked antsymmetry into your choice of basis/notation. You might want to add a definition of what precisely $\varepsilon^I$ means.

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks I updated with the precise definition. I think I may understand what you mean. The only step where the notation plays an important role is the final equality, which certainly uses anticommutativity of the wedge product c.f. the proof in Lee. So really we aren't using anticommutativity of $*$, but anticommutativity of the wedge product to show that $* = \wedge$. Is that correct?

Comment: The idea is that, by your defintion, $\epsilon^I$ are not independent; $\epsilon^I=\pm\epsilon^J$ if $J$ is a permutation of $I$. This implies that any operation satisfying $(\star)$ is anticommutative on $1$-forms.

Comment: @Kajelad Oh I see. So really it's a matter of $\star \implies $ anticommutativity of $*$.